# "Coordinate day" how to write correctly

Tags: grammar

> I want to coordinate with you this day

or

> I want to coordinate this day with you

What sentence are correct or they are interchangeable ?

Comment: For example someone ask me: let me know a day when you will affordable to call. And I say: I can be affordable next week on Friday but I want to coordinate this day with you. Is this a right sentence ?

Comment: You mean *available*, not *affordable*. Also, can you use different words to explain what you want to say? Do you mean "I can be available next week on Friday, tell me what time is good for you.*?

Comment: Catija, it also not bad example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your purpose is to encourage the other person to tell you what time of day works for them, here are some more common ways to say that:

You're not trying to coordinate a whole day, just a point in the day, so at the most, you'll be *coordinating a **time***.

> I can be available next week on Friday. Let's coordinate a time for the call.

Or, more fully:

> I can be available next week on Friday. Let's coordinate to find the best time for the call.

*Discuss* can also be a good option for this:

> I can be available next week on Friday. Let's discuss a good time for the call.*

If you want to give them the option to say that Friday is not a good day for the call, you can add:

> I can be available next week on Friday. If this works for you, [insert option from above].

If you want to say this more casually:

> Friday next week is good for me.  What time works for you?